# Where did the guideline of writing automated unit tests for public methods (only) originate?

Tags: unit-testing

The question is simple: there is no shortage of opinions that state automated unit tests are to be written only for public methods.

What is the authoritative source and argument behind this *best practice*?

Comment: Why does everything require a single origin? I think it is simply the experience of a majority of expert developers who posted their common knowledge initially on Stackoverflow, and other places and later, after this site was created, also here. Moreover, I don't like the term "best practice", since many devs confuse this with "law". It is rough guideline, no less, no more.

Comment: Why would this be a "best practice"? A good API exposes powerful functionality through a simple interface. Many, many modules have internal routines that are complex enough to profit from being closely covered by automated tests.

Comment: @DocBrown It was just phrased like it. If it has multiple origins feel free to share. The "experience of a majority" is an empirical statement. Is this shown in any authoritative way to be true?

Comment: @KilianFoth Do you write automated tests for methods with less than public visibility? Which exactly? Is it not a design issue if that complexity is spread around private methods and cannot be tested via the public interface? There are opinions that say so.

Comment: @ragnacode: well, instead if "I think" I should have written "I guess". This is simply my personal observation when I remember the posts here on this site and on Stackoverflow about this topic. Feel free to use the search feature of these sites and try "unit test private" or "unit test public" as search keywords, then sort the results by date in ascending order.

Comment: I thought of this first, 10min before you posted. Let the iteration commence!

Comment: It's a guideline. You are free to test whatever you want to test. You should try to only write tests where having the test gives you any benefit; that is common sense. You should think about the purpose of unit tests. Do you have other reasons to have unit tests?

Comment: @gnasher729 The issue, in my opinion, goes well beyond the "you are free to test..." mindset into business and engineering imperatives that require identifying subtle misunderstandings or gaps in requirements, particular levels of reliability and robustness for the products and maintaining constancy in these metrics, and a level of independence of factors like turnover, heterogeneity in skill levels and perspectives, etc; and using automated testing as a tool aligned with these imperatives. Therefore, this guideline must be sufficiently good to address these issues. How do we know this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise, and the "accepted answer" is not an answer to it, so it will only confuse readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single origin for most things. Best practices are best practices because they work well. Things that work well are generally "discovered" by mutliple people independently of one another. What can be said about some sort of origin is, that it most likely does not predate Structured Programming. While it is possible to write unit tests for procedural programming they are a lot easier with structured code. Especially **global scope** might be an issue. I'd go even a step further that unit tests did not become popular before modular programming emerged in the 1960s, tho I have no useful sources to back up this claim.

The earliest mention of Unit testing I can find is the following. Sadly I can't find the PDF anywhere any more.
[image: EvoTest: Test Case Generation using Genetic Programming and Software Analysis by A Seesing in 1954]

1954 would be about the time structured programming came into existence tho I am not convinced that this Paper really is from 1954. There is a paper from 1958 explaining the idea of unit tests for teachers which might have been an inspiration:

[image]

[Source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/808591?casa_token=ENSOKFyGZKYAAAAA%3AJQw1mpY9IIjjnFxoJJeglBNxXQsDed-U1DwR5Hx28SQafWA6qzCoDK0KNRzCWXii2-vYU6kUXI89StWLcKfWPY34IktBc9QxTcVY3X1XWjXWInoocTg&seq=1)

However the first paper that I can find is this one from 1978:
[Automatic Software Test Drivers](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1646913/references#references) which references a paper from 1975 called "Automated Unit Test (AUT) Program Description/Operation Manual" but I sadly can not find the original source for it. What we can say with certainty is that Unit testing must have originated before 1978 (1975) and might have been known (and perhaps used) as early as 1954 tho I somewhat doubt this. It was definetly known in 1958 as a test idea for school children.

Comment: I think you are confusing what "structured programming" is. Michael Jackson came a lot earlier than object oriented programming.

Comment: Sorry what? Michael Jackson?

Comment: The question was not about the origin of "unit testing", and the fact the OP accepted it anyway shows how nonsensical the question is.

Comment: @DocBrown You are indeed correct. I missed that after starting to write this answer

Answer (score 3):

Exactly one of these things is true about a private member:

- In some way, it gets called when at least one of the class' public members are interacted with.
- It is not used and can be safely removed.

Either your private method should be removed because it is not in use, or it is already part of the public behavior in some capacity; therefore it is sufficient to test a class' public behavior as it will inherently touch on all *used* private members.

Secondly, the measure of whether a class works as expected (which is precisely the purpose of a unit test) is defined by how it publically behaves. What it does privately is irrelevant to anyone but the class itself. Therefore, there is never a specific need to test a private member directly, as no one but the class should even know of the member's existence in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In most OO languages it is simply not possible to call a private (or protected) method from a unit test. So it is not really an opinion or "best practice" when you don't have the choice. The "authoritative source" is the language design.

Comment: This is not accurate. I can use techniques that allow me to test private methods.

Comment: @ragnacode: You mean like reflection? That is generally not recommended as a way to circumvent private. (Otherwise, what would be the purpose of having private methods in the first place?)